# Angular2 authentication Services

Tags: angular2-services

I am trying to load local JSON data to angular console,with AuthHttp.

getData(){

```
   let trail = this.authHttp.get('app/_services/admin.json')
  .map(res => res.json())

  console.log('hello',trail);
  return trail;
}
```

Instead of the actual JSON data, im getting below observable

Observable {_isScalar: false, source: DeferObservable, operator: MapOperator}

Please help me in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: JSON is text, so please edit your question and paste it as *text*, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

It is because angular2 `get()` method returns an observable, to get the value you must `subscribe()` the returned value..
So in your code it should be like:

```
trail.subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
    // the response should be json now
});
```

Comment: i tried subscribing but its not going into subscribe ,so no logs are displayed in console.